# How can I create commit functionality of git using java?

Tags: java, eclipse, git

I am a new user of git. I am working to extend git functionality in eclipse on a local repository on my own system using java. I have to develop commit functionality of git using java. Can you please help exactly which libraries I should import for committing and version control? Is there any other library that I need to install in eclipse for the same? If it is, pl make me available a link for that.

Comment: What does this have to do with Swing?

Comment: Eclipse already has git support, which is opensource, so you could look into extending the [Egit plugin](http://www.eclipse.org/egit/)

Comment: @MarkRotteveel Yes I know that Eclipse has git support but the thing is that I have to commit a random folder from my system to my local git repository. I need to code for the same. I had already gone though the Egit plugin link. Pl help.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to implement Git functionalities in Java a good library is [JGIT](http://www.eclipse.org/jgit/).

> JGit is an EDL (new-style BSD) licensed, lightweight, pure Java library implementing the Git version control system:

And again:

> JGit has very few dependencies, making it suitable for embedding in any Java application, whether or not the application is taking advantage of other Eclipse or OSGi technologies